# datatables.net fixedColumn not rendering properly

Tags: datatables-1.10

I use datatables.net. Initialization works just fine. (taken from the samples)

My problem occurs when i start using "fixedColumns" extension. (see picture)

[image]

i installed packages with bower

```
"datatables.net": "1.10.12",
"datatables.net-bs": "1.10.12",
"datatables.net-fixedcolumns": "3.2.2"
```

Any help?

Comment: Is fixedHeader.dataTables.css included in the src of datatables.net-fixedcolumns? Is the CSS file linked into your project (if you are using grunt or gulp?) I have epxerienced a lot of weird problems with bower and npm packages of various dataTables distros, hard to know if you really have a bad package or is using a bad setup.

Comment: @davidkonrad i think you gave me the clue. I will discard the bower packages and start from scratch from CDN :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As i stated out i was using bootstrap theme for datatables.net i also had to use bootstrap theme for "Fixed columns".

I didn't include this in my bower file.

Correct bower file:

```
"datatables.net": "1.10.12",
"datatables.net-bs": "1.10.12",
"datatables.net-fixedcolumns": "3.2.2",
"datatables.net-fixedcolumns-bs": "3.2.2"
```

Be sure to add `fixedColumns.bootstrap.min.css` in your markup. I was missing that too.